# JAXB based on inheritance like XML-Nodes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am pretty new to JAXB so I'm not sure if it is even possible what I want to do.

I have an XML file where I basically configure something like run parameters for my program. Certain configurations share a large amount of the same parameters and only differ in 1 or 2. So my XML currently looks like this:

```
<Parameters id="1">
    <Attribute1>value1<Attribute1>
    <Attribute2>value2<Attribute2>
    <Attribute3>value3<Attribute3>
    <Attribute4>value4<Attribute4>
    <Attribute5>value5<Attribute5>
</Parameters>

<Parameters id="2">
    <Attribute1>value1<Attribute1>
    <Attribute2>value2<Attribute2>
    <Attribute3>value3<Attribute3>
    <Attribute4>otherValue4<Attribute4>
    <Attribute5>otherValue5<Attribute5>
</Parameters>
```

I am looking for a way to reduce the redundancy in this, so that I have a base configuration that is then extendend and in the extension I just have to configure the Parameters that are different.

```
<Parameters id="1">
    <Attribute1>value1<Attribute1>
    <Attribute2>value2<Attribute2>
    <Attribute3>value3<Attribute3>
</Parameters>

<Parameters id="2" parent="1">
    <Attribute4>value4<Attribute4>
    <Attribute5>value5<Attribute5>
</Parameters>

<Parameters id="3" parent="1">
    <Attribute4>otherValue4<Attribute4>
    <Attribute5>otherValue5<Attribute5>
</Parameters>
```

Worth mentioning the set of attributes for the parent node are not fixed for different groups of configurations i.e. in other cases Attribute1 might the one that is changing. Is this even possible with JAXB?

### Question Update

I guess my initial description of the problem scenario was a bit unclear / left out some details.

My parameter setups are all individual nodes in one xml file under the same root node. I'm using XPATH to retrieve single parameter nodes and unmarshal this node into a Parameters object.

So far so good, but what I now want to do is to restructure my xml by using some kind of inheritance to reduce redundancy. When loading the node with the id="2" for example I want my Parameters object to inherit the values of node with the id="1".

### Solution

My solution to this problem is done in two simple steps. In the first step I just load the object from the XML node. Then I check if the node has a assigned parentId. If that's the case I also load the object for the parent and copy the fiedl values to the child object, if they aren't already set.

```
public static Parameters createParams(String id){
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new File("src/test.xml"));
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parameters.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    Node n = (Node) xPath.compile("/config/Parameters[@id='"+id+"']").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
    Parameters p = (Parameters) unmarshaller.unmarshal(n);  

    if(p.parentId != null)
        p.loadValuesFromParent(createParams(p.parentId));

    return p;
}

public void loadValuesFromParent(Parameters parent) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
    for (Field field : Parameters.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if(field.get(this)==null){
            field.set(this,field.get(parent));
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: So what you want? Pojo classes to represent new XML?

Comment: Kinda. I want 1 Pojo with attributes1-5 and how I can use JAXB to create my object with all 5 attributes for my nodes with id 2 & 3.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, this can be achieved by any simple pojo, unless there is something missing in the question, that is special.

Sample pojo with main.

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement()
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parameters {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String parent;

    @XmlElement(name = "Attribute1")
    private String attribute1;

    @XmlElement(name = "Attribute2")
    private String attribute2;

    @XmlElement(name = "Attribute3")
    private String attribute3;

    @XmlElement(name = "Attribute4")
    private String attribute4;

    @XmlElement(name = "Attribute5")
    private String attribute5;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parameters.class);
        Marshaller marrshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marrshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        Parameters p1 = new Parameters();
        p1.id="1";
        p1.attribute1="value1";
        p1.attribute2="value2";
        p1.attribute3="value3";
        marrshaller.marshal(p1, System.out);

         p1 = new Parameters();
        p1.id="2";
        p1.parent="1";
        p1.attribute4="value4";
        p1.attribute5="value5";
        marrshaller.marshal(p1, System.out);

         p1 = new Parameters();
        p1.id="3";
        p1.parent="1";
        p1.attribute4="Othervalue4";
        p1.attribute5="othervalue5";
        marrshaller.marshal(p1, System.out);
    }
}
```

And the three xml outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<parameters id="1">
    <Attribute1>value1</Attribute1>
    <Attribute2>value2</Attribute2>
    <Attribute3>value3</Attribute3>
</parameters>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<parameters parent="1" id="2">
    <Attribute4>value4</Attribute4>
    <Attribute5>value5</Attribute5>
</parameters>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<parameters parent="1" id="3">
    <Attribute4>Othervalue4</Attribute4>
    <Attribute5>othervalue5</Attribute5>
</parameters>
```

Comment: I guess my initial question was a bit unclear. Fortunately I've found a solution by myself. I'll update the original post later.